# Inequality regarding the smallest real part of eigenvales

Tags: matrices

Define $Re\lambda_{min}(A)$ to be the minimum of the real parts of the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$. Let $A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be two matrice such that $Re\lambda_{min}(A)>0$, $Re\lambda_{min}(B)>0$ and $Re\lambda_{min}(A-B)\geq 0$. Is $Re\lambda_{min}(A)\geq Re\lambda_{min}(B)$ right? And how to prove.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Typo in the title; typo in your final inequality

Comment: Can you do this for $2\times 2$ matrices?

Comment: It seems wrong: take just A=diag(10+epsilon, 1) B=diag(10,2)

Comment: Alexander, A-B=diag(epsilon,-1) in your example so it doesn't work.

Comment: @Felix, yeh, you right, I misread as abs(Re(Lambda_min))...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a $2 \times 2$ counterexample:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}10 & 19  \\\\ 8 & 16\end{bmatrix}$

$B=\begin{bmatrix}9 & 2 \\\\ 17 & 7\end{bmatrix}$

If you have tacit assumptions, share them and we'll see if the statement becomes true!

Comment: (@Felix: For the matrix display: you have to use FOUR backslashes instead of 2...)

Comment: @ Tom De Medts, thanks, this is great!